# how to make frequent commits so my sql delete query won't time out

Tags: sql, db2, spring-batch

I have a couple of update/delete queries as part of individual tasks in my Spring Batch project that are timing out because they are deleting large sets of records.
Since these are just update and delete queries I implemented them as Tasklet steps which are not chunk-oriented.

How can I make frequent commits so that I can avoid timeouts.

```
public class DeleteTask implements Tasklet {

    private static final String DELETE_QUERY = "DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'TEST'";
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    public DeleteTask(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        log.info("Purging IMCO records from MYTABLE table...");
        try {
            jdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_QUERY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Failed to purge  records from MYTABLE table due to:");
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("Records purged");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Exception states:

```
 StatementCallback; SQL [DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE LOB_CD = 'TEST'[jcc][t4][2055][11259][4.14.113] The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has terminated all requests in progress, 
ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=58009; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientException: [jcc][t4][2055][11259][4.14.113] The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has terminated all requests in progress,
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? How many rows are you deleting? How many rows does the table have?

Comment: Not sure how many rows the table has but we're talking in the tens of millions. 
I am attempting to delete about 7 million rows.
EDited the post to show exception

Comment: Have you increased the connection/transaction timeout value?

Comment: Where is this added?

Answer (score 1):

A simple SQL compound statement would maybe be the best method

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE DONE BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;  
    --
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' BEGIN SET DONE = TRUE; END;
    --
    WHILE NOT DONE
    DO
        DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COL1 = 'A' FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY)
        COMMIT;
    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Looks good @Paul Vernon, In this case, would I have to change SQLSTATE '02000' to the particular code I am getting in the exception above?

Comment: No, that SQLSTATE is “no rows found”, so the loop continues until all qualifying rows are deleted

Comment: If my answer works for you, feel free to accept it or up vote  it

Comment: Ok cool thanks Paul, Will check it out once I get back to my machine and am able to test

Comment: ```An unexpected token "DO" was found following "WHILE NOT DONE```

Comment: What Db2 version are you using? Boolean variables are newish

Comment: v10.5.0.10 seems pretty new

Comment: 10.5 is old enough to be out of base support https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-distributed-end-support-eos-dates , so I would not describe it as “pretty new”

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two strategies:

**Increase the query timeout**

You can use `java.sql.Statement.setQueryTimeout()` to increase the timeout for a particular query, but this can help you only up to some point.

**Delete in batches**

The other option is to run the `DELETE` statement iteratively, limiting the number of deleted rows, until no more rows are deleted (so all are gone). You can add `FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY` to a `DELETE` to achieve this.

For example:

```
create table t (a int);
insert into t (a) values (1001);
insert into t (a) values (1002);
insert into t (a) values (1003);
insert into t (a) values (1004);
delete from t fetch next 2 rows only;
select * from t;
```

Result:

```
A
----
1003
1004
```

Every time you run the query it tells you the row count of deleted rows. Keep running it until the returned count is zero.

For your particular case you'll need to tweak the batch size. For example for 10k rows at a time you can use `FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY`. A higher number will be faster, but can also risk a timeout.

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=31419a10ee8404bb6224c5b0c19fc1f1).

Comment: In addition to deleting in batches (with a commit per batch), you want to carefully verify that the DELETE statement that gets run is *correctly indexed* (so double check the access plan), otherwise you will be doing multiple table-scans which will massively slow down the query and cause concurrency issues.  In addition, if you know the __percentage__ of the rows that you will purge by this action, and that percentage is more than 60% of the rows, then a smarter strategy can be to copy the 40% of rows into a temporary table , truncate the table (unlogged), then copy back the 40%.

Comment: Makes sense to use frequent commits. Thanks for the example @The Impaler, 
I guess my last question would be how do I incorporate re-running the query?
What kind of loop/condition would I use so that it exits once all rows are gone