# JDBCTemplate delete record in batches and commit transaction

Tags: java, database, transactions, db2, batch-processing

I am deleted records from a table using `JDBCTemplate` in DB2 which fills up transaction logs throwing error.

Delete query:

```
delete from table 
where col = 'A'
and not exist (
  select 1 from table2
)
```

Exception:

```
The transaction log for the database is full.. SQLCODE=-964, SQLSTATE=57011, DRIVER=4.21.29
```

This will delete 2.5million records from the table.

What is the best way to handle this exception from code.

I am thinking about selecting the records into a Object in java then deleting in batches and commiting transaction after every delete batch execute.

Comment: Are you doing this in production environment or while developing?

Comment: If you are dividing the delete's in chunks, it's likely that the log size wont be affected. Usually you need to make a backup after some deletes, thus the log will be empty. Or increase the log file size, if that's an option.

Comment: we will do it in DEV first if works.. we will run it in PROD

Comment: I think the transaction log file is getting filled up because all the deletes are happening in 1 transaction. If i do it in chunks after every batch commit or rollback, it will clean transaction log.

Comment: I don't think that's how the log works. It should contain all changes after last backup, so it can be "replayed". Otherwise you would loose changes.

Comment: If this is a onetime task, create a service window, make a backup, run the deletes, make a backup again.

Comment: It is done through job which runs every day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make frequent commits so my sql delete query won't time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64467564/how-to-make-frequent-commits-so-my-sql-delete-query-wont-time-out)